# Is there any advanced open source pop3 class for php?

Tags: php, email, pop3

I am looking for an advanced open source pop3 class for php. For outgoing mails im using phpmailer, and i need pop3 class to handle incoming mails(read, delete. decode).

Thanks for reading and your help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Zend Mail](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.read.html) has extensive functions for the reading of email messages. (Note that the components of the Zend Framework can be used as single elements, no dependencies to the framework)

Comment: Sounds promising. i will check it out. thanks for info Peter!

Comment: It can be used as a module, i.e. without Zend (Zend/Mail, Zend/Mime folders + Zend/Mail.php, Zend/Mime.php)